# Find the sum of a probability of dice roll that is prime.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Consider rolling n fair dice. Let p(n) be the probability that the product
of the faces is prime when you roll n dice. For example, when n = 1, one die is
rolled and the probability that the result is prime is
p(1) = ${\frac{|\{2,3,5\}|}{|\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}|}}$=$\frac{1}{2}$

When n = 2, two dice are rolled and the probability that the product of the
two dice is prime is
p(2)=  $\frac{|\{(1,2)(2,1),(1,3),(3,1)(1,5)(5,1)\}|}{|36|}=\frac{1}{6}$

When n = 3, three dice are rolled and the probability that the product of the
upturned face values is prime is p(3) = $\frac{1}{24}$ .
Find the infinite sum of p(n) (when n starts at 0)
(Hint: Consider differentiating both sides of the infinite geometric series:
infinite sum of r^n( when n starts at 0)= $\frac{1}{(1-r)}$ when abs(r)<1)

I can differentiate the two sides of the geometric series but I'm lost regarding what to do after that. I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: First, can you find a general formula for $p(n)$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: I think it would be p(n)=1/(n!)?

Answer (score 3):

You will get a prime product if exactly one of the faces is prime and the rest are all 1. The probability (binomial distribution) that you will have a prime product with n dice is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{1}.(\frac{1}{2})^1.(\frac{1}{6})^{n-1}$

So you need to find $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(\frac{1}{6})^{n-1}$

Replace $\frac{1}{6}$ by $x$. Now consider the geometric sum $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... x^n + ...$. What happens when you differentiate it term by term wrt $x$? Especially consider what happens to the general term $x^n$.

Now find an expression for the geometric sum in terms of $x$ and differentiate that wrt $x$. Finally substitute $x=\frac{1}{6}$. That should give you the required sum.

Post a comment if you still have difficulty.

Comment: What do you mean by wrt x?

Comment: With Respect To x. Common acronym.

Comment: Thanks. So when I differentiate the geometric sum wrt x I get $$1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}+...$$ 
Then the expression for the sum of x is $\sum_0^\infty x^n$ and differentiating that wrt x is $\sum_0^\infty nx^{n-1}$ and it is equal to $\frac{n}{1-x}$ and by substituting $x=\frac 16$ you get $\frac 65 n$ ?

Comment: No. You have the right summation expressions. But what you need to do is find the expression for the geometric sum first. What is the sum of an infinite geometric series with first term 1 and common ratio x?

Comment: It's $\frac {1}{1-x}$, right?

Comment: Exactly. Now differentiate that expression with respect to x. That will give you an expression for the sum you require. Sub the $\frac{1}{6}$ back into it. Remember to multiply the whole thing by half at the end.